# Android camera api creates a null file

Tags: android, android-camera

Hi I am trying to use camera api in my app, to take pictures with, it also works fine, with takeing pictures and save it, but then I choice Camera and press back button, without taking pictures, it creates a file with 0kb, how do I fix this?

```
private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE = 100;
private static final int RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE = 101;

private void ShowDialogForChoose() {
    final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, new String[] {
                            "Camera", "Gallery" }),
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                            int which) {
                            if (which == 0) {
                                Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(
                                        android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

                                cameraIntent.putExtra(
                                        MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                                        getTempUri());
                                // Lav check om der er primission til at bruge camera
                                startActivityForResult(cameraIntent,
                                        CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE);
                            } else if (which == 1) {
                                Intent i = new Intent(
                                        Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                                        android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                                startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
                            }
                        }
                    });
    builder.create().show();
}

private Uri getTempUri() {
    // Create an image file name
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss");
    String dt = sdf.format(new Date());
    imageFile = null;
    imageFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            + "/Fitness/", "Camera_" + dt + ".jpg");
    AppLog.Log(
            TAG,
            "New Camera Image Path:- "
                    + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    + "/Fitness/" + "Camera_" + dt + ".jpg");
    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            + "/Fitness");
    if (!file.exists()) {
        file.mkdir();
    }
    if (!imageFile.exists()) {
        try {
            imageFile.createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    imagePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Fitness/"
            + "Camera_" + dt + ".jpg";
    imageUri = Uri.fromFile(imageFile);
    return imageUri;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it creates a file with 0kb

No, *you* create a 0KB file, via your call to `createNewFile()`.

> how do I fix this?

Delete your call to `createNewFile()`. That is not necessary.